# How to show icons?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to solve the problem with invisible icons?

HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head> 

<body>
<i class="fa fa-angle-up">cos tam</i>
</body>
```

CSS

```
@import url("fontawesome.min.css");
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAiuV.png)

Comment: Try to import style like this: `@import 'fontawesome.min.css';`

Comment: What code are you using to show an icon?

Comment: @prettyInPink I changed

Comment: try this. @import url("css/fontawesome.min.css");

Comment: @Nikita still not working

Comment: or @import url("newsletter/css/fontawesome.min.css"); 
just consider about directory of html and css

Answer (score 0):

Check which version you are using, based on that you might need to change the classes.

https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/angle-up?style=solid

From the folder image you shared it is located at the same level as your main.css, so your path should be correct:

`@import url("fontawesome.min.css");`

But try in case:
`@import url("../css/fontawesome.min.css");`

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css");
```

```html
<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the link tag from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome , and add that in the head section.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
    awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head> 

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-up">cos tam</i>
</body>
```